# when I used an anchor tag in email body it's going to spam folder

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer, spf, dkim

Actually I am facing a lot of problem about email sending. When I am trying to send a email using a module named phpmailer that contains an anchor tag or hyperlink as like

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

email go to the spam folder but when i remove this anchor tag or remove the link from the body of the email its send properly and goes to inbox.
i do not get what was the problem.
i am using a shared hosting with cpanel.
please anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all links? Or just links to a particular site?

You might want to check that the site you're linking to isn't listed in [SURBL](http://www.surbl.org/surbl-analysis) or similar blacklist.

It's also worth inspecting headers on received messages - spam filters will often add headers telling you why it classified a message as spam.

Generally there is nothing specific you can do - if there was an obvious way to avoid spam filters then spam senders would use it and the filters would be useless. That said, almost every receiver uses entirely different spam filtering, so your results may vary enormously anyway.

Comment: Hey Synchro, I am also getting the same issue. I am using Gmail id and my HTML code is  $email_body="<a href='http://www.domin.com/changepassword.php?user_id='" .$User_id1. ">Create your password here</a>";

Comment: Well the same advice applies: Check your headers.